# Factoring $4x^4 + 12x^3 - 24x^2 - 32x$

Tags: polynomials

Some help with factorizing this polynomial please. I have tried but it is difficult as it factorizes down to a cubic and I can't factorize it further. This is regarding the division of polynomials.

$$P(x) = 4x^4 + 12x^3 - 24x^2 - 32x$$

Comment: 3 high reputation user jumps at an easy question, which had no attempts... i think i am starting to observe a pattern here

Comment: You could at least have *tried* to experimentally find *at least* one simple root of the cubic.

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

Taking out $4x $ as common, $4x^4+12x^3-24x^2-32x=4x(x^3+3x^2-6x-8)$

Now, $3x^2-6x=3x(x-2), x^3-8=x^3-2^3$

Answer (score 2):

[Factor theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_theorem) will help.

$$4x^4 + 12x^3 - 24x^2 - 32x=4x(x^3+3x^2-6x-8).$$
Here, letting $f(x)=x^3+3x^2-6x-8,$ we have
$$f(-1)=0.$$
This implies that $f(x)$ has a factor $(x-(-1)).$
So, we have
$$4x(x+1)(x^2+2x-8).$$
Then, you'll know how to proceed from here.

Comment: please cross check the line: "Here, letting $\cdots$"

Comment: @labbhattacharjee: Thank you for pointing it out!

Comment: Thanks this was the best. I got 4x(x + 1)(x + 4)(x - 2) - which is correct.

Comment: @Simon: My pleasure!

Comment: @Simon, so why don't you accept this?

Answer (score 1):

You can factor $4 x$ first. Now, by inspection, you could find that $x=-1$ is a solution. Now, reduce from cubic to quadratic and continue.

I am sure you can take from here.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this could help:
$$4x^4+12x^3-24x^2-32x=(4x^4-24x^2)+(12x^3-3x)=4x^2(x^2-6)+4x^2(-6-\frac8x)$$
Then we can sum the two terms
$$4x^2(x^2-12-\frac8x)=4x^2(\frac{x^3-12x-8}x)=4x(x^3-12x-8)=4x^4-48x-32x$$
Hope this would help

Peterix

Answer (score 0):

Start by:
$$P(x) = 4x^4 + 12x^3 - 24x^2 - 32x=P(x) = 4x(x^3 + 3x^2 - 6x - 8)$$
Then one root is $x=-1$. So divide by $(x+1)$ and get simpler second order  polynomial.

In general, if you interested in result rather than the way, much websites like [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) can solve this problems, doing for you the long and sometimes ugly way. All you need to do is to feed the polynomial and get [this result](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=4x%5E4%20%2b%2012x%5E3%20-%2024x%5E2%20-%2032x) saying it is $4 x (x+1) (x-2) (x+4)$.

Comment: I need the working out.